# How can I run MATCH query on replica?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've found some leering materials and setup for Memgraph related to on project that I should pickup up after the summer break. The setup is Dockerized environment. I have MAIN Memgraph instance and REPLICA. Memgraph version is 2.4.1

When I try to run this query on MAIN it works, but on REPLICA it fails:

`MATCH (:Driver { id: 1 })-[:ASSIGNED*1]->(sector:Sector) RETURN sector;`

The message that I get is: `Query failed: Write query forbidden on the replica!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in Memgraph 2.5.1. Try to run you query on 2.5.1 and it should work.